# Using Spring 4.0 with spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring 4.0 in my JavaEE application, and I tried to use the Spring-data-jpa.

However when I add the Spring-data-jpa dependency, I found that the Spring-data-jpa will depend on Spring-3.x.

Then I wonder this will cause any problem? Since my application will have Spring-4.x with Spring-3.x.

Anyone have the same experience?

---

Update:

I am using Spring-data-jpg-1.4.3:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I run `mvn dependency:tree` I got this:

```
+- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
+- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.6.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.2:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.1:runtime
+- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.4:compile
+- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE:test
```

It seems that the spring 4.0.. is mixed with spring 3.1.4..

Comment: Never mix spring versions that is trouble waiting to happen. The Spring data 1.4.x branch should work fine with Spring 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an error in the **spring-data-jpa 1.4.3.RELEASE** pom denepdency. 
What actually happens is that it loads spring dependencies that exist in this maven pom instead of the ones you want to import. 
The short answer is add this as a parent to your maven project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC5</version>
</parent>
```

so that it can inherit the correct dependencies.
 
Another way to solve this is to use the `<exclusions>` tag to exclude them and then import the correct dependecies but this takes more time and is not as clean. If you don't want to add **spring-boot-start-parent** though, then this is how to solve this error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
         ...
        </exclusion> 
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

For more info see **[here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.0.RC5/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven)**